# JS best practive and secure check for value from user without getting undefined - using a mini function

Tags: javascript, security

Let's say I want to check user's input like this:

```
if (a.b.c.d[0]=="Something")
```

and user does not going to send this, therefore I will get an undefined error.

Functions are here to make programming easier.

So I have made something like this:

```
function value(str) {
    try {
      return eval(str);
    } catch(err) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  let a = {
    b: {
      c: {
        d2: ["Something"]
      }
    }
  }

  // Now I can easy check for the incoming value;

  if (value("a.b.c.d[0]"))
    console.log(value("a.b.c.d[0]"));
  else
    console.log("No");

  // this going to return "No" instead of crash the whole app
```

It returns good results - returns the actual value to be directly compared in the if statement. And when undefined it returns `null`.

Since I am controlling what to send to this eval - I will never send danger data - like `alert('xss');`

However, I still concern `eval` will be danger here - will it be?
As you can see I am not using it for the user's input, but only for string that I have sent manually.

So my question - is this a good practice to determine the user's input like this?

This question is about security and best practive of JS.

Comment: You really don't need neither `eval` or `try..catch` here, for you use case (because you don't need to distinguish `false`, `null` or `undefined`), all you need to do is `if(a && a.b && a.b.c && a.b.c.d && a.b.c.d[0]=="Something")`

Comment: you are totally right @Kaddath ... but be honest ... this is ugly isnt it ? ;)

Comment: What do you mean by *user input*? Just `str` argument is used in the `try...catch` block. It would be better to use `str != null` or `str !== undefined && str != null` conditions instead. Also it is possible to use a default argument value.

Comment: @L4B0MB4 after trying code with many nested `try..catch` where you can't find where the error comes from, you may find that it's not that ugly, it does what it needs to do, no more

Comment: @L4B0MB4 Not as ugly as unnecessary `eval`s. If ugliness is a concern, then build a function to parse `"a.b.c.d[0]"` and return the result. Much more control that way compared to `eval`.

Comment: Why that I will parse the input manually if there could be a function/service doing this for me?

Answer (score 1):

You don't **have** to use `eval` here. All you need to do is to ensure that all properties in the path exist before accessing their child properties.

This can be done using something like this:

```
Boolean(a && a.b && a.b.c && a.b.c.d && a.b.c.d[0] == "Something");
```

Here the short circuit AND operator (`&&`) ensures that `a.b.c` is not accessed if `a.b` evaluates to falsy. So the code doesn't throw an error in such scenarios.

```js
function checkValue(a) {
  return Boolean(a && a.b && a.b.c && a.b.c.d && a.b.c.d[0] == "Something");
}


let a = {
  b: {
    c: {
      d2: ["Something"]
    }
  }
}

console.log(checkValue(a));

a = {
  b: {
    c: {
      d: ["Something"]
    }
  }
}
console.log(checkValue(a));
```

Comment: You must see how this if far less flexible and readable than the eval solution, right?

Comment: @FINDarkside Yes, but (A) you don't have to go three layers down very often, and (B) security is far more important than readability. Also there are various ways of simplifying this. For example, you could at some point rename `a.b` into another variable `x`, so your validation becomes `x.c && x.c.d && x.c.d[0]...`.

Comment: @FINDarkside and also much very much safer, who knows, your user may want to try to call the function with malicious code inside..

Comment: @Kaddath Of course, but as you can see from my answer, you can do it in a secure way while still avoiding this, which OP is probably trying to avoid. If he didn't need to use the value function in multiple places, he could just wrap the a.b.c.d[0] in try/catch.

Comment: @FINDarkside But then your solution would be slower due to the property enumeration. There is always a trade-off.

Comment: @FINDarkside yep i have nothing against your solution, which is a nice generalization, it's the `eval` solution that bothered me

Comment: @NisargShah Premature optimization, it's very unlikely that there will be performance problem, especially considering that it's a lot faster than the eval solution. Clean and a bit slower code is most often better than ugly but fast.

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely not good practice and completely unecessary. While there might not be any big security hole **yet** it's really easy for it to turn into one. You can do the same thing without eval like this:

```js
function value(obj, str) {
  const arr = str.split('.');
  for(let s of arr){
    if(obj[s] === undefined)
      return undefined; // Or throw error?
    obj = obj[s];
  }
  return obj;
}

const userThing = {a: {b: {c: {d: ["something"]}}}};
console.log(value(userThing , "a.b.c.d.0"));
```

Comment: There could be an easier function runs without re-declaring the whole thing two times.

Comment: @Raz I'm not sure what you mean. You're not declaring anything two times here.

Answer (score 0):

> This question is about security and best practice of JS

The rule is that you do not trust what is sent to the server by the client.

It means that what you receive from the client must be controlled **by the server** in order to be processed. The standard which discusses this is OWASP, specifically [Testing for Input Validation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Input_Validation).

Now, you may want to check for input on the client, but not for security. You may want, for instance, to ensure that all relevant fields are filled in - but in any way whatever you receive should be considered malicious.

Comment: I am not going to trust the user input. I am sending the texts to the eval function bymyself as you could see. Will never be there any parameter came from user.